# Use Qt codes in C++

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, qt

I have some codes in Qt Creator that work properly. I need to use this codes but in win32 application in .net framework. Does anyone have any idea how can I do this? I am totally new to Qt and do not know how to use this useful codes in c++ project?

I appreciate any help in advance

I think I could not get my message across. Qt is c++ but It has some differences with the native c++ app that we use in .net framework. so I can't just copy all the codes in my project to run it properly. Can we make a dll or library to use this qt code in .net or not? and how can I do this?

I really need help. Thank you so much

Comment: Qt code is C++. I don't understand your question. Just copy/paste the code you need. Or stick with Qt.

Comment: There is Qt SDK in windows.

Comment: AFAIK, .NET framework has its own GUI/Windowing library. So, it's would be better to stick with that. However, it should be perfectly possible to use Qt from a native (non-CLI) C++ application if the environment is setup right. Could you please clarify which is it that you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @BhargavBhat whole purpose of Qt is to not use natvie GUI/Windowing library.

Comment: Do you have an existing .Net application in which you want to integrate Qt code? Note that a "native C++ app" is definitely NOT using the .Net Framework. They're in fact opposite. A native C++ app runs directly on the CPU, a managed .Net app runs in the .Net Virtual Machine.

Comment: @Mat Qt code is not pure C++. It has some extensions like signals and slots mechanism, qobject_cast() and various other things on which Qt app may rely. Qt sources are pre-compiled by *moc* (meta object compiler).

Comment: @Kamil: IMO using Qt on a C++/CLI is simply inappropriate. It makes sense for a pure/native C++ app because C++ doesn't have windowing stuff of its own and Qt could help write portable applications. Now for C++/CLI code the framework or runtime would be expected to provide the necessary libraries, including windowing/GUI classes irrespective of what platform you're on. Using Qt here doesn't give you any advantage, only hassles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For almost all cases, you do not want to mix .net and Qt in same application. It's less work to just take the logic and rewrite it for .net (managed C++ or C#).

Next best option might be to keep the parts separate and have them communicate through some IPC mechanism.

This is, because any non-trivial Qt code depends on it's own event loop, so getting the existing Qt code play nice with other event loop is always a hassle, and trying to get it play nicely when actual application is managed .net code... No, just no, unless you have a very compelling reason, are expert on both Qt and .net, and have extra time to make it work right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you don't know how to download and install Qt or how to create a Qt project in Visual Studio IDE. Try this [installation guide](http://portfolio.delinkx.com/files/Qt.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to link the Qt library to your win32 c++ app? I think you should build the qt source code first with your win32 compiler. I think you could include the qt header and link the library as normal win32 library to your application after that.

Comment: Qt requires moc before using some of its constructs.